# Adding data from a list to a database in Flask using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have an array of data.

```
experience =[{}, {}, {}] #list of 3 objects
project = [{}...]
```

I want to send it to the database. I have created the models also.
So to add the list to the database I did the following:

```
# Add data to the database within the app_context() function
with app.app_context():
    # Commit changes

    # Add data to the database for projects
    for project in projectData:
        project_entry = Project(
            projectName=project["projectName"],
            projectDescription=project["projectDescription"],
            projectUrl=project["projectUrl"],
        )
        db.session.add(project_entry)

    # Add data to the database for experiences
    for data in experience_data:
        experience_entry = Experience(
            companyName=data["companyName"],
            companyDescription=data["companyDescription"],
            companyUrl=data["companyUrl"],
            companyRole=data["companyRole"],
            companyDuration=data["companyDuration"],
            companyLocation=data["companyLocation"],
            companyResponsibilities=data["companyResponsibilities"],
            projects=data["projects"]
        )
        db.session.add(experience_entry)

    # Commit changes after adding all data
    db.session.commit()
```

The issue here is that the data from the array keeps getting committed each time it loads. I beleieve this should only container 3 rows but I have up to 54 rows.

what am I doing wrong ?

If I also take it out of the app.app_context() I get an error of the app is being ran out of context.

how to do I store this data only once?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs.

**1) Uniqueness constraints.**

You can specify the combination of fields in each table, that is determine  uniqueness of each row.

Then if you try to insert item (row) that already exists in the table (for example, project with the same `projectName`; or experience with the same combination of `companyName`, `companyRole` and `companyDuration`) database will tell you that such row is already exists in the database (database will return the error).

To avoid returning errors you can do `select` query before inserting to check whether the data with this combination of fields already exists in the DB.

**2) Redirect to another URL to avoid multiple inserts by refreshing the web-page.**

If you don't want to specify the uniqueness constraints, but need to avoid situations when data is being inserted into the DB every time user refreshes the page, you can specify the method of this route as `POST` and in the end of your endpoint function (after the data is inserted) do redirect to another `GET` route, that just returns data.